# Assuming there is no wind, do two raindrops of different sizes fall at the same speed?

Tags: gravity

Assuming there is no wind, do two raindrops of different sizes fall at the same speed?

Simple enough question. Look forward to your answers.

Comment: First we have to decide what shape is a raindrop. It is _not_ raindrop shaped, not a sphere. It is more flat like a red cell, but I am guessing the shape depends on speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The drag force due to the atmosphere would be larger for the larger raindrop, resulting in a reduced acceleration. Therefore, the smaller raindrop would start moving faster in time.</strike>

Eventually, you will have two rain drops falling at terminal velocity. The faster rain drop will be the one with less surface area perpendicular to the motion.

edit: Sorry, that is not entirely true. Although the larger raindrop has greater surface area ( and thus larger drag force ) it also has greater mass. So if you re-arrange,say, $F_d = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 C_d A = F_g = mg$ for velocity you get $$v^2 = \frac{2mg}{{\rho}(A)(C_d)}$$ where $\rho$ is density of the fluid, $A$ is surface area, and $C_d$, the drag coefficient, is $C_d \propto \frac{1}{v}$

The faster raindrop would be one with greater mass and less surface area perpendicular to the motion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics) for more information about drag

Comment: Mass $\propto r^3$ and area $\propto r^2$ and so $\frac{\text{mass}}{\text{area}} \propto r$.  However the droplets will not be exactly spherical.

Comment: I realize the shapes probably change between the two during the fall. That's why I tried to generalize it to mass divided by the surface area perpendicular to the drag force. I unfortunately cannot give any more information. The correct answer probably belongs to someone else.

Comment: I think that your answer is a good one.  For very small drops the drag force might be dependent on the velocity rather than the velocity squared.

Comment: I really want to downvote this because it's so wrong. The smaller the drop, the lower its terminal velocity. If a drop gets small enough it will be almost stationary. What do you think holds clouds up?

Comment: The first paragraph is simply wrong. Acceleration is net force divided by mass. And net force is gravity minus drag.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast What do you think is wrong with my statements specifically?

Comment: @Floris I edited it to compensate for the misunderstanding in the beginning paragraph. It is not known to me whether the drag force for the larger rain drop would be larger or smaller, actually.

Comment: @Obliv - The downward force is proportional to the mass of the drop, or the cube of the radius, while the area is proportional to the square of the radius. So, if you double the radius you octuple the mass and quadruple the area. Then the downward force of the larger drop is 8 times the smaller, but at the same speed the drag is only 4 times larger. If the forces are balanced for the smaller at some terminal velocity, at that velocity the larger will still be able to accelerate. So a larger drop has a larger terminal velocity than a smaller drop. This is basic square-cube behavior.

Comment: $Cd$ is **not** constant. It changes with speed.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast What if the shape of the raindrop no longer takes on the shape of a sphere? I imagine the drop takes multiple forms during its fall. Then mass is no longer proportional to radius cubed. Likewise, the surface area is no longer the square of the radius. That's why I'm not able to come to the same conclusion as you.

Comment: @ja72 I'm pretty sure $C_d$ is constant when terminal velocity is reached, no?

Comment: Two drops of the same mass at different speeds have different $C_d$ but similar area $A$. Two drops of different mass at the same speed may have similar $C_d$ but will have different area $A$.

Comment: @Obliv - I've no links to back be up, but I've seen photographs of water droplets at terminal velocity, and they were roughly spherical. Surface tension is not to be ignored.

Comment: @Ja72 the $C_d$ for both raindrops will be the same until some velocity $v_a$ where $a$ is the point where one of the drops is moving faster than the other. after this point, the drop that is moving faster, say drop $A$, will be experiencing an increased drag force. Whether that influences $A$ to start decelerating is up to how the mass and surface area of $A$ affects the drag force (I think).

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I have seen too photos of droplets and they look like disks actually.

Comment: @Obliv - Such considerations have been studied. See here http://engineering.utsa.edu/~ftestik/files/Towards-elucidating-the-microstructure-of-rainfall-a-survey.pdf for several terminal velocity models, all of which have terminal velocity increasing with drop diameter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean about "assuming there is no rain" but larger raindrops do have a faster terminal speed than smaller drops.

EDIT: Here's a [whiteboard video](https://youtu.be/ax8NKp7zXn8) using Stoke's law to explain why.

Comment: Sorry, meant no wind.